# Formotion Promotion RubyMotion

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, rubymotion

stuck on this one.

I've just been playing around with RubyMotion and now ProMotion. I'm just making a todo style app, just to learn a few things. I'm having trouble with saving my data into a file. Ignore saving the data for now, im just trying to find the correct function that gets called once the submit button is pressed.

I've gone through the github pages of both Formmotion and ProMotion, but the only thing i can find of any use to me is this one on ProMotions page, https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion/wiki/Guide:-Formotion-or-other-custom-UIViewControllers

But even then it doesn't tell me (or i'm missing something) on which helper is called when the submit button is pressed.

Any help would be great, cheers guys.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a block to the on_submit method of your form.

This block will be called when a submit button is pressed

```
@form.on_submit do |form|
  # do something with form.render
end
```

https://github.com/clayallsopp/formotion#retrieve

Answer (score 0):

Devon is correct, but this is something we should address in ProMotion. For now, do this (expanding on Devon's answer):

```rb
class MyFormScreen < PM::FormotionScreen
  title "My Form Screen"

  def table_data
    # ... formotion hash
  end

  def on_load
    self.form.on_submit do |form|
      # form.render
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: FYI, I already created a pull request to add `on_submit` to our next minor release of ProMotion (1.1.0). https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion/pull/280

Answer (score 0):

struggling through with this stuff myself.  however this one bit iv'e got working.  again, expanding on Jamon's answer

```
class MyFormScreen < PM::FormotionScreen
  title "My Form Screen"

  def table_data
    # ... formotion hash
  end

  def on_load
    self.form.on_submit do |form|
      data = _form.render      
      PM.logger.debug data[:alarm_time]      
    end
  end
end
```

... that's assuming you have the FormotionScreen working using either the Promotion-Formotion Gem or your own similar Class as per the link in the question